# How can I put PHP into a php echo?

Tags: php

I've a simple problem but I am a php beginner so I need your help.

I want to put a php echo into a php echo. I know that this is not possible but idk how to solve my problem.

There is a simple html list which shows the subjects only if the assigned value in the db is >0.

```
<li>
    <ul>
        <?php  if ($record['#1'] > "0") { echo "<li>#1</li>"; }?>
        <?php  if ($record['#2'] > "0") { echo "<li>#2</li>"; }?>
    </ul>
</li>
```

But I also want to show the whole list only if one of the values is >0 because otherwise the list will be empty. So I need something like this (I know it doesn't work this way):

```
<?php  
  if ($record['#1'] > "0" or $record['#2'] > "0") { 
     echo "
        <ul>
          <?php  if ($record['#1'] > "0") { echo "<li>#1</li>"; }?>
          <?php  if ($record['#2'] > "0") { echo "<li>#2</li>"; }?>
        </ul>
       </li>
     "; 
   }
?>
```

Comment: `<php` should be `<?php` for one thing. But if this is already a part of the string you need to either use ternary operators and concat it to the string, or build the final string dynamically.

Comment: Sorry, it's of course `<?php`. The first code works for me but the second one doesn't.

Comment: I'm assuming that this is part of a bigger string? Show the full code.

Comment: The whole code is really long because it has a lot of this list points.

Comment: Alright. The point is that you cannot do `echo "some string".if ($condition) { echo "add more strings"; }."foobar";`, as it seems as you are doing. Which is why a bit more code surrounding this block will allow us to see what you're actually trying to do, and in turn help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this code as:

```
<ul>
<?php
  if($record['#1'] > 0)
    echo "<li>#1</li>";
  if($record['#2'] > 0)
    echo "<li>#2</li>";
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are alredy in the PHP-Tag. So don't open it again. 
Close and Open echo if you want. Link this:

```
<?php  
  if ($record['#1'] > 0 || $record['#2'] > 0) { 
     echo "
        <ul>
          "; if ($record['#1'] > 0) { echo "<li>#1</li>"; } echo"
          "; if ($record['#2'] > 0) { echo "<li>#2</li>"; } echo"
        </ul>
       </li>
     "; 
   }
?>
```

Or you are looking for a way how looks a bit better, like:

```
<?php  
  if ($record['#1'] > 0 || $record['#2'] > 0) { 
     $li1 = "";
     if ($record['#1'] > 0)
          $li1 = "<li>#1</li>";

     $li2 = "";
     if ($record['#2'] > 0) 
          $li2 = "<li>#2</li>";

     echo "
        <ul>
          $li1
          $li2
        </ul>
       </li>
     "; 
   }
?>
```

Add 2 Strings:

```
$foo = "blabla";

echo "I say:".$foo." and soooo"; // <- I say:blabla and soooo
echo "I say:$foo and soooo"; // <- I say:blabla and soooo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  if ($record['#1'] > 0 OR $record['#2'] > 0 ) { ?>
  <ul>
    <?php if ($record['#1'] > 0) { echo "<li>#1</li>"; } ?>
    <?php  if ($record['#2'] > 0) { echo "<li>#2</li>"; } ?>
  </ul>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
<?php
    if ($record['#1'] > "0" || $record['#2'] > "0") { 
        echo "<ul>";
        if ($record['#1'] > "0") {
           echo "<li>#1</li>"; 
         }
        if ($record['#2'] > "0") { 
           echo "<li>#2</li>"; 
         }
      echo "</ul>";

 }

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please change the code given below

```
<?php  if ($record['#1'] > "0" or $record['#2'] > "0") {  ?>
  <ul>
    <?php  if ($record['#1'] > "0") { echo "<li>#1</li>"; }?>
    <?php  if ($record['#2'] > "0") { echo "<li>#2</li>"; }?>
  </ul>
</li>  <?php }?>
```

I think you forgot the syntax of the php tag. So please change like this and try

Comment: If you see the final `<li>";` it suggests everything is being echoed already, in which case it won't work with PHP-tags and `if`s inside. Not my downvote btw :-) (I nearly walked into the same trap)

Comment: @Qirel this is correct please see carefully.

Comment: Like I said, it's not my downvote. But that `";` that's at the end of the string in the original question suggests that OP wants to put all this in the middle of a string - which won't work.

Comment: @Qirel Sorry i got your point. Thanks.

Comment: That's right. The first snippet is the current code. So you can see that I've already a php string which should be included into another.

Comment: @elkloso  see my code you will get your answer.